# Usage of singular and plural forms in proper nouns

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Should we say "Samsung Electrical **Appliance**, LLC" or "Samsung Electrical **Appliances**, LLC"? Should "appliance" be in the singular or plural form? Why?

Comment: That's not a proper noun. You don't need to use the plural form in your example.  There are exceptions though, for example "a drinks company" is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+drink+company%2C+a+drinks+company&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) than "a drink company".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Noun adjunct: dispute tribunal](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/289327/noun-adjunct-dispute-tribunal). Bottom line: ***Attributive nouns** (noun adjuncts) are [chiefly, but not always, singular*.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/289327/noun-adjunct-dispute-tribunal#comment539951_289737)

Comment: @BillyKerr Actually 'Samsung Electrical Appliance' *is* a proper, compound noun. It's the name of a company, and there's only one of them.

Comment: Voting to close. It isn't a question about learning English, it's a question about naming conventions of businesses.

Comment: BillyKerr is commenting on an earlier version of the question. I guess I should not have edited the question. Rather, I should have posted a new one. It is my fault. I am sorry!

Comment: @AwsAl-Jashami no it's OK, you can edit questions here to make them clearer. No worries.

Comment: @Astralbee - the question has been edited since my comment. Originally it wasn't a proper noun, but it is now. So, no problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.  There is no grammar rule to remember here, you just find the name of the company.  The actual name of this company is:

> Samsung Electronics Home Appliances America, LLC

It is a subsidiary of Samsung Electronics Co. Ltd, the registered name of 삼성전자 주식회사 for trading on the London Stock Exchange. The American subsidiary is a an LLC, and I assume that you are referring to this subsidiary, not the Korean parent company.

That is the name of the company. It doesn't have to follow any rule it just is.

Both "Samsung Electrical Appliance, LLC" or "Samsung Electrical Appliances, LLC" are incorrect, not because they break any rule, but simply because there is no company named Samsung Electrical Appliance[s].

If you were naming a company, you would use "Samsung Electrical Appliances" because the company makes appliances, many of them, so the plural would be a better choice of name.

Moreover, 99.9% of the time you won't actually need the formal company name. You would just say "Samsung"  You would only need the formal name if you were, for example, filing official paperwork for the company.

Comment: Wow! I never thought of such an elaborate answer! Honestly, I was "manufacturing" this question for another reason .. to make a kind of comparison .. I may elaborate later on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a guideline for the future.  Ask the question you actually want to ask.  Don't manufacture a question to illustrate a point about your actual question. If you don't want to know about Samsung, don't ask about Samsung!

Answer (score 0):

That's the name of a company. If you want to be technically precise, use the official name of the company. If the company's name violates some spelling or grammar rule, basically that's too bad. Like I saw a post on another forum where someone asked what he should do when a person spells their own name wrong. If he means, "His birth certificate says Jeorg but the correct spelling is George", no, that's not the correct spelling. The correct spelling is whatever is on his birth certificate.

Of course in real life we rarely refer to a company by their full, official name. Like if the official name of a company is "Smith Electrical and Electronic Parts and Supply Corporation", most people -- including the company's own employees -- are just going to call it "Smith Electronics" or "Smith's".